# how does the retweet mechanism work on twitter?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, while-loop

I'm creating similar thing to twitter retweet function!

This is my database table for tweets (status messages):

```
ID || USER_ID || TWEET || RETWEET_ID || RETWEET_NAME || DATE
```

What I'm trying to  find out is, if the logged in user retweets something, when they refresh the page I don't want them to see the retweet button (because obviously they have retweeted it).  I'm more concerned with the app logic; it's driving me crazy.

p.s. a user's timeline is queried using a while loop array, so it has to distinguish between a normal tweet, and retweeted tweet, if you get my drift!! :))

EDIT: another thing is if it's a normal tweet, both values RETWEET_ID and RETWEET_NAME are NULL, so that's how I can differentiate between the two!!

Comment: i was thinking to have a seperate retweet table, and then i can reference it!!

Comment: That sounds like the better idea instead of having those extra fields in your tweets table. Then you'll know if a user has rewtweeted something using a simple query looking for tweet_id + user_id

Comment: yeh defo i was thinkig that aswell!!! :)) cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options

1) You use similar to what you have now

```
ID || USER_ID || TWEET_TEXT || RETWEET_ID || DATE
```

But drop the retweet name. If each tweet id is unique, then your tweet would contain either a tweet_text or a retweet_id.

2) The second option, and better solution would be to have two tables, tweets and retweets.

```
TWEETS { ID || USER_ID || TWEET_TEXT || DATE }
RETWEETS {ID || USER_ID || RETWEET_ID || DATE }
```

The second option is cleaner, and will mean you will not have empty columns in your database, but the first option will make your querying easier, as you do not have to join the two tables, or create a view over the table etc.

Comment: i like the second option, but im still confused

Comment: same here. i want to know too. if i use 2nd option how to sort out result with tweets and retweet?

Answer (score 0):

just to add from my perspective a few tips, you could also add to both tables the time and date of the tweet and retweet, once you have the json data and manipulated it to become a dictionary like object in your backbend code, you can just join both results and sort it by time and date. So this way always appears like an ascendant order. Great day.

Edit: also, as every tweet have a unique Id, for retweets you could create the key joining the Id of the person who retweeted it and the tweet key. I don't see the point to create new IDs for retweets, but that is my opinion. Thanks for reading.